# Cosa sono "i nottolini della strada"?

Tags: meaning

Nel *Gattopardo* di Tommasi di Lampedusa ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Questi pensieri erano sgradevoli come tutti quelli che ci fanno comprendere le cose troppo tardi e l’aspetto del Principe, la sua figura, divennero tanto solenni e neri che sembrava seguisse un carro funebre invisibile. Soltanto la violenza con la quale i **nottolini** della strada venivano schizzati via dall’urto rabbioso dei piedi rivelava i conflitti interni; è superfluo dire che il nastro della sua tuba era vergine di qualsiasi cartello ma agli occhi di chi lo conoscesse un “sì” e un “no” alternati s’inseguivano sulla lucentezza del feltro.

Non riesco neppure a poter in certo modo "dedurre" dal contesto cosa possano essere questi "nottolini della strada" di cui parla il testo? Magari i sassolini che trovava il Principe di Salina al suo passaggio? Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegarlo?

Ho ricercato alla [voce "nottolino" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI11/00000601.jpg), ma non mi sembra di trovare nessuna accezione che possa avere senso nel brano citato sopra. Ho anche datto un'occhiata ad altri vocabolari, ma il GDLI mi è parso il più completo.

Comment: Voto per chiudere questa domanda perché non si tratta di una questione d'italiano, ma di tipografia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sembra si tratti di un refuso. Si tratta di [ciottolini](https://books.google.it/books?id=WNerkZI2NxEC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=questi%20pensieri%20erano%20sgradevoli%20come%20tutti%20quelli%20che%20ci%20fanno%20comprendere%20le%20cose%20troppo%20tardi%20e%20l%E2%80%99aspetto%20del%20principe,%20la%20sua%20figura,%20divennero%20tanto%20solenni%20e%20neri%20che%20sembrava%20seguisse%20un%20carro%20funebre%20invisibile.%20soltanto%20la%20violenza%20con%20la%20quale%20i%20nottolini%20della%20strada%20venivano%20schizzati%20via%20dall%E2%80%99urto%20rabbioso%20dei%20piedi%20rivelava%20i%20conflitti%20interni;&source=bl&ots=a2URwho4Hi&sig=ACfU3U06Mgx2acJyBAetsF424siBQL15Ag&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRo4vzlZLuAhUDH-wKHdqADCcQ6AEwAnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=ciottolini&f=false):

> Soltanto la violenza con la quale i **ciottolini** della strada venivano schizzati via dall’urto rabbioso dei piedi rivelava [...].

Comment: Scusa ma il link non stava in un commento. Poi cancello la risposta.

Comment: Complimenti per aver trovato la spiegazione. Ma un “typo” sarebbe una specie di refuso?

Comment: Una volta in più, si tratta di un errore tipografico, quindi di una domanda fuori tema. Guardate [questo](https://books.google.es/books?id=cbCOCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT111&lpg=PT111&dq=%22Soltanto+la+violenza+con+la+quale+i%C2%A0nottolini%C2%A0della+strada+venivano+schizzati%22&source=bl&ots=KZD2S5p82r&sig=ACfU3U1DVRyw-l28KmdpjoTaUzVmcXw2Lg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy8ISOo5LuAhURZMAKHbWUBosQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=nottolini&f=false), però, che è l'edizione che ho io (veramente non è mia: è di una biblioteca del centro di Barcellona, che ha perlomeno 20 copie, perché l'usa per un club di lettura. Curioso!

Comment: Secondo me, puoi perfettamente lasciare questa risposta, Hachi, anche se ho chiuso la domanda come off-topic (magari cambiando "typo" in "refuso" o "errore tipografico", come suggerisce @DaG nel suo commento). Penso possa essere utile a altri lettori dell'edizione Feltrinelli che ho io.

Comment: @Charo - *“perché l'usa per un club di lettura”*. Non sono sicuro sia scorretto, ma è sicuramente   insolito scrivere o anche dire *“l’usa”* per *“li o le usa”*.

Comment: @Hachi: In realtà, io mi riferivo all'*edizione*.

Comment: @Charo  - si, anche come contrazione di “la usa” è insolito.